# Raindroplet simulations

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, objects, particles, physics

I’m currently working on a short film. I’m not an expert at Blender so I decided to ask for help here.  I watched this youtube tutorial on how to make rain droplets:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0koL5NGBaA0&t=25s

Now I wonder how to get rain droplets to slide around two gauges I have modeled. The droplets in this tutorial don't behave the same way in my blender file and I feel like I have trouble tweaking it so that the water would slide around the two models.

If I don’t find a good solution for making this effect soon I will try to film a transparent glass behind a green screen and glue two cylinder-shaped green cups or something so that the water goes around the cup's edges and then chroma key the green out in Premiere Pro. I don’t know how well it smooths around the droplets if I green screen it though. (I don't have money for After-Effects at the moment.) so I figured that I try to do it somehow in Blender instead.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Try using metaball. But if you film this directly, don't use green screen, film the water using a black background and then use a luma key.